# Creating a template with multiple data sets using the QuickSight API, from Python 3/boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-quicksight

I'm a bit stuck with the QS API, for a template with multiple data sets. The API, for boto3 says this (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_template):

```
    SourceEntity={
        'SourceAnalysis': {
            'Arn': 'string',
            'DataSetReferences': [
                {
                    'DataSetPlaceholder': 'string',
                    'DataSetArn': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
```

I'm trying to pass this to `DataSetReferences`:

```
[{'DataSetArn': 'my-dummy-arn1',
  'DataSetPlaceholder': 'my-dummy-placeholder1'},
 {'DataSetArn': 'my-dummy-arn2',
  'DataSetPlaceholder': 'my-dummy-placeholder2'},
 {'DataSetArn': 'my-dummy-arn3',
  'DataSetPlaceholder': 'my-dummy-placeholder3'}]
```

To my untrained eyes it looks like QS expects a `list` of `dicts`, which should be the data structure I'm passing. However, I get this:

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateTemplate operation: Expected 1 placeholders. Given 3

Am I misreading the API docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the root cause and it was user error.

In case someone else bumps into this:

Check the manually configured source analysis (QS does not have automatic source analysis creation/restore/save, neither through the CLI, nor the API or some other means).

The number of placeholders needs to match the number of data sets in the source analysis.